# How to configure Google Authentication using IdentityServer4 avoiding external authentication error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, identityserver4

I am trying to configure Google authentication for my app using IdentityServer4. Here's my configuration code:

```
    private static IServiceCollection AddGoogleAuthProviderServices(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var googleExternalAuthProviderSettings = configuration
            .GetSection(nameof(GoogleProviderSettings))
            .Get<GoogleProviderSettings>();

        services
            .AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = googleExternalAuthProviderSettings.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = googleExternalAuthProviderSettings.ClientSecret;
                options.SignInScheme = googleExternalAuthProviderSettings.SignInScheme;
                options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            });

        return services;
    }

    private static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServerServices(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var clients = configuration
            .GetSection(ClientsSectionKey)
            .Get<IEnumerable<ClientSettings>>()
            .Select(settings => new Client
            {
                ClientId = settings.ClientId,
                ClientName = settings.ClientName,
                RequireClientSecret = settings.RequireClientSecret,
                AllowedGrantTypes = settings.AllowedGrantTypes,
                RedirectUris = settings.RedirectUris,
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = settings.PostLogoutRedirectUris,
                AllowedCorsOrigins = settings.AllowedCorsOrigins,
                AllowedScopes = settings.AllowedScopes,
                EnableLocalLogin = false,
            });

        var apiScopes = configuration
            .GetSection(ApiScopesSectionKey)
            .Get<IEnumerable<ApiScopeSettings>>()
            .Select(settings => new ApiScope
            {
                Name = settings.Name,
                DisplayName = settings.DisplayName,
            });

        services
            .AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryClients(clients)
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(apiScopes)
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

        return services;
    }
```

The appsettings:

```
{
  "GoogleProviderSettings": {
    "ClientId": "xxx",
    "ClientSecret": "yyy",
    "SignInScheme": "idsrv.external"
  },
  "ApiScopes": [
    {
      "Name": "Exchange",
      "DisplayName": "Exchange"
    }
  ],
  "Clients": [
    {
      "ClientId": "xxx",
      "ClientName": "front",
      "RequireClientSecret": false,
      "AllowedGrantTypes": [
        "authorization_code"
      ],
      "RedirectUris": [
        "http://localhost:8080"
      ],
      "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
        "http://localhost:8080"
      ],
      "AllowedCorsOrigins": [
        "http://localhost:8080",
        "http://localhost:5105"
      ],
      "AllowedScopes": [
        "Exchange"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my configuration in google developer console:
[image]

localhost:5003 is my IdentityServer4 service address and the localhost:8080 is the place where the frontend application besides. While trying to authenticate from the frontend app im being redirected to google. Then when i sign in im getting an error from ExternalController.Callback function.

```
System.Exception: External authentication error
   at IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.ExternalController.Callback() in C:\Projekty\rtail\src\backend\IdentityService\Quickstart\Account\ExternalController.cs:line 87
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you able to expand on what exactly is throw that exception and why? It looks to originate in your application code and it's code that would only be invoked had the Google sign in completed successfully. What does the ExternalController.Callback method look like?

Comment: @mackie The stack trace i've sent is all i have. I also think, since the callback is called, the Google sign in is completed. I've also tried to change the provider to Microsoft Account, and after configuring it, the result is the same as in here. I've tried to debug it and in general the problem starts in the CookieAuthenticationHandler class. [Here the NoResult is returned](https://pasteboard.co/yRS6h07cNPDb.png). Im not sure do i need any additional configuration for cookies, cors or smth because it looks like it can't find the cookies. The sign-in-scheme is idsrv.external

Comment: My thought is that a cookie is being blocked indeed, the external claims will be stored in that idsrv.external cookie and then loaded inside ExternalController.Callback. If it was me I'd check the browser network log to see if any cookies are being blocked.

Comment: @mackie you were probably right - if i understand it correctly the cookie is blocked. [Here's my log](https://pasteboard.co/Xuve2gyqbTHE.png). It looks like that im missing Secure specification in correlation cookie. However i needed to specify SameSite for this cookie because in other way i was getting "Correlation not found" error. It looks like that i need to use https instead of http. Do you know any solutions? Thanks for an effort and excuse me my dumbness, however im new to this stuff. Regards

Comment: I think you'll just have to use HTTPS for local dev, .Net Core makes that pretty simple though.

Comment: And this was exactly the case man. When i changed the redirection Uri of mine service to use https - it worked :) Thank you so much for help. Regards